# How to Integrate a PHP form with Smarty?

Tags: php, forms, smarty

I am trying to add a web contact form to a website that uses Smarty PHP templates.

My initial attempt (below) produces a blank webpage.

**.tpl file**

```
{debug}
{extends file='toxtweet.tpl'}
{block name=body}
    <form action="" method="post">
    {foreach from=$formitems as key=name item=value}
        <label for={$name}>{$value}</label>
        <input type="text" name={$name} size="50"/>
    {/foreach}
    <input type="submit" value="E-mail" />
    </form>
{/block}
```

**.php file**

```
<?php
   include 'base.php';
   include './scripts/recaptchalib.php';
   $formitems = parse_ini_file("formitems.ini");
   $smarty -> assign('formitems',$formitems);
   $smarty -> display("contact.tpl");
 ?>
```

`base.php` and `toxtweet.tpl` work fine in all the other pages so I don't think they are the problem. `recaptchalib.php` has the proper path.

If remove the `{foreach} ... {/foreach}` lines, the blank webpage displays properly. The error persists if I use the format `{foreach $x as $y}` or `{foreach from=$x key=k value=v}`.

The debug shows that the `ini` file with the values for `formitems` was loaded properly.

Comment: Have you written in your code `{/foreach}` or `{\foreach}`?

Comment: @bwoebi {/foreach}, sorry for the typo. Fixed in the OP.

Comment: $value needs to be wrapped in {}

Comment: @JibranKhan Thanks for spotting that syntax error. There's still something else wrong though. I still get a blank page. :-/

Comment: Is $formitems (in PHP) actually an array? Try and view the source from the browser. You might see errors there if it's a syntax error.

Comment: also you need to remove "as" from your foreach. :)..

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it is an array- I can see it properly in the Smarty debug console.

Comment: @JibranKhan After removing the "as", the form displays. I love you guys.

Comment: @JibranKhan - make this an answer so mac389 can mark the question as solved :-)

Comment: @mac389 - ok, I saw that you solved it now. Good :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "as" from your foreach and it should work.